# the mapping class group of the disk is trivial proof

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Proof :

Identify $D^2$ with the closed unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $\phi : D^2 \rightarrow D^2$ be a homeomorphism with $\phi_{\partial D^2}$ equal to the identity. We define,

$F(x,t) = \begin{cases} (1-t)\phi(\displaystyle\frac{x}{1-t}) & \text{$0 \leq |x| < 1 - t$} \\ x & \text{$1 - t \leq |x| \leq 1$} 
\end{cases}$

for $0 \leq t < 1$ and we define $F(x,1)$ to be the identity map of $D^2$. The result is an isotopy $F$ from $\phi$ to the identity.

What exactly is going on here in this proof visually? What is $F(x,t)$ telling us? I am not sure what the proof is doing here.

Answer (score 4):

Just imagine you extend $\phi$ to a homeomorphism $\Phi$ of the whole plane by setting $\Phi(z)=\phi(z)$ whenever $|z|\leq 1$ and $\Phi(z)=z$ whenever $|z|\geq 1$. Then $F(\cdot,t)$ is obtained by considering $\Phi$ on a large disk and scaling that disk to be of unit size. You basically compress the area where the original $\phi$ is active to a disk of radius $1-t$, outside of which $\Phi$ acts as the identity.

Comment: So basically whats happens is that at $t = 0$ you get $\phi(x)$ but as $t$ gets closer and closer to $1$ the radius of the disk gets really small which basically means that we are contracting the disk arent we? Are we contracting the disk to a single point and then applying the identity map outside the point?

Answer (score -1):

Every map defined on a contractible space is nullhomotopic. So$ MCG(D^n)$={$id^*$.}

*:Of course, you may work in different categories and you want your maps to be either 
isotopic , diffeomorphic, etc. So,in the broadest sense,i.e,  up to homotopy alone, $$MCG(D^n)$$ is trivial.(If  we only mention a homotopy,  this is what we want ). Now, considering isotopies,  since $D^n$ is homeo. to $\mathbb R^n$ , and $MCG (\mathbb R^n)=$ {$\pm Id$} , it all comes down to deciding if $Id$ ~ -$Id$ . But, e.g., (for n=2 )$-Id \circ -Id$ (maybe unfortunate shorthand for the isotopy $z \rightarrow ze^{i\pi t} ; t \in [0,1]$) gives you an isotopy from $-Id$ to $Id$ , so you are then done.

Comment: Do tell, what is wrong here?

Comment: pretty sure if you knew, you would have written something.

Comment: The Mapping Class Group doesn't define equivalence via homotopies.  The equivalence is via isotopies, which are homotopies *via homeomorphisms*.  This means you need to make sure each stage of the homotopy is a homeomorphism, which is a much more difficult task than just showing every map is nullhomotopic.

Comment: @MartianInvader:Please see my edit.

Comment: You assert that $MCG\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right) = \{\pm Id\}$.  The standard proof of this is to show $MCG(D^n)$ is the identity using the proof in the question, so you're using circular reasoning.  Also, $-Id\circ -Id$ is not an isotopy.

Comment: Well, I know of a proof that does not use this fact, so there is no circularity within my layout. And a rotation by $\pi$ is an isotopy (at least for n=2).

Comment: So, I guess you can guarantee that all proofs that $MCG (\mathbb R^n)$ _necessarily_ use that $MCG (D^n)=Id$, and that rotation by $\pi $ for $n=2$ is not an isotopy, in order to counter my proof. You have not done either.

Comment: A few points: 1) I wasn't the one who downvoted, I was just trying to help you understand what was wrong with your answer. 2) "I know of a proof of this" isn't a good answer, especially when the question is specifically asking for clarification of a different proof.  3) A rotation by $\pi$ is a not an isotopy, it's a homeomorphism (albeit one that is isotopic to the identity).  I'm not sure what construction you're trying to do here, but $-Id$ typically refers to an orientation-reversing transformation, such as reflection along a single axis. 4) You're pretty defensive, so I'm done here.

Comment: I didn't mean to come off as offensive, sorry; I wish you had let me explain myself before concluding I was wrong, which I was upset about . My map is actually z->ze^{i\pit} ;t in [0,1], which is a homeo. for each t, and has the continuous inverse e^{i(-t)}.

Comment: I perceived you determined to show me I am wrong  --I do not believe I am-- and lecturing me, instead of examining my argument fairly.

Comment: Thanks for your input; it was helpful.

Comment: @MartianInvader : So the map $z(t) \rightarrow ze^{i\pi t} $ described by user 99680 is not an isotopy between Id and -Id ? I don't see why? Isnt each map a homeomorphism and $z(0)=z, z(1)=-z$ ?

Comment: @Gary. That map is an isotopy.  My comment above was made before that was edited in and was simply written as $-Id \circ -Id$, which is confusing shorthand at best and downright incorrect at worst.  Again, I didn't downvote, but I didn't upvote this answer because it provides a muddled and incomplete argument that doesn't at all address the original question, which presents a wholly different argument and asks "What exactly is going on here in this proof visually?"